# DOM taking a long time to update after element added

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have some code to append an element to a div. When I try it on my computer, it's fine. But when I try it on my phone, it (on Chrome debugger) shows that the element appears in the "Elements" view, but it takes a long time before it shows up on the actual screen.

My code is:
`$('.addField').click(function(){
        this.parentNode.innerHTML = this.parentNode.innerHTML + '<div class="block"><input class="noBorder name" type="text" placeholder="Name"><input class="noBorder value" type="text" placeholder="Value"><a class="removeField" href="#">X</a></div>';
    });`

Comment: Please show us all your code, it may be that you have something delaying it unintentionally.

Comment: What exactly does "a long time" mean? A second? 10 seconds? More? Also what sort of phone do you have - when was it manufactured? Is it new? Old?

Comment: @Pointy It is a fairly new Android phone, and I have used multiple, and it doesnt work. 5 seconds around for the delay

Comment: @Script47 I have updated the code, all I'm using is a click handler.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what I'm asking. I'm asking how to fix these bug and am trying to resolve this issue without dealing with obnoxious people nitpicking everything I type. Maybe instead of putting my post on hold with no explanation, you could suggest some fixes to me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Adding an element by performing an `innerHTML` update like that means that the browser has to remove and clean up the previous DOM subtree, parse the new HTML content, and build a whole new set of DOM nodes.

You'd be better off creating the new elements and appending them with `.appendChild()`.

*edit* — a better way to do that with jQuery is

```
$('.addField').click(function(){
  var block = $("<div/>", { "class": "block" });
  block.append($("<input/>", {
    "class": "noBorder name",
    placeholder: "Name"
  }))
  .append($("<input/>", {
     "class": "noBorder value",
     placeholder: "Value"
  }))
  .append($("<a/>", {
    "class": "removeField",
    "href": "#",
    "text": "X"
  }));
  $(this).parent().append(block);
});
```

Comment: I have already attempted to use jQuery and it had the same error.

Comment: @Tyler see the update to the answer.

Comment: I tried that, and still around a 5-7 second delay. Thanks for the input though.